# How to set default URL/route?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm implementing AngularUI's routing and appear to be missing something about how to configure a default URL.  It seems like the below code would default the user to `/dashboard/tree` but if I refresh the page, the url appends another `/dashboard`, so I end up with `/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard/tree`.

How can I properly set the default URL without having this appending issue when the user first visits the page?

```
config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard/tree');

    /* URL mappings */
    $stateProvider.
        state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            views: {
                'page': {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/admin/dashboard.htm'
                }
            }
        }).
        state('dashboard.tree', {
            url: '/tree',
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/admin/tree-overview.htm'
                }
            }
        });
}])
```

Comment: Try this :  
    `.otherwise({redirectTo: "/dashboard/tree"})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not, this is probably a bug/feature in angular 1.1.5 (reloads add stuff to the url).

Try setting this in your head:

```
<base href="/"></base>
```

Comment: Having the `base` tag keeps the URL from appending to itself.  However when my base is `/admin` I still have to include /admin in routing for AngularUI

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  The whole appBase base thing is in motion.  See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2969 .  I'm trying to stay abreast and informed on how this will pan out.