# ui.router 'otherwise' doesn't seems to work

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get ui.router to work with the following setup.

```
export class Router {
    /* tslint:disable no-unused-variable */
    private static $inject: string[] = ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider"];
    /* tslint:enable no-unused-variable */

    constructor($state: ng.ui.IStateProvider, $urlRouter: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider, $location: ng.ILocationProvider) {
        $urlRouter.otherwise("/");

        $state.state("default", {
            url: "/",
            views: {
                "header": {
                    templateUrl: "/views/layout/header.html"
                },
                "sidebar": {
                    templateUrl: "/views/layout/side-menu.html"
                },
                "": {
                    templateUrl: "/views/workspace/index.html"
                },
                "footer": {
                },
            }
        });

        $location.html5Mode(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the partial file I'm using.

```
<div id="workspace">
    <div id="workspace-header">
        <div data-ui-view="header"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="workspace-container">
        <div>
            <div data-ui-view="sidebar"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div id="workspace-view">
                        <div data-ui-view></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="workspace-footer">
                        <div data-ui-view="footer"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure it's related (or whether it's a problem) but the html above is injected using ng-include like so.

```
<div id="dashboard" data-ng-include="'/views/master.html'" data-prevent-touch-scroll></div>
```

Just to be clear I verified that the router gets called.

I thought that 'otherwise' would navigate to the url and it would transit into the default state which will inject the partial views but it doesn't seems to work, I'm sure I'm missing something but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: In these case, plunker would always help. Does it work without html5?

Comment: I'll make an example and update it.

Comment: I tried to make this work in Plunker but it seems like it throws 404 for my style.css and app.js..

Comment: Which version of Angularjs are you using? Have you tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200231/how-to-set-default-url-route

Comment: I'm using version 1.3.0-rc.5.

I do have the base tag as part of my page, it seems like a problem with ng-include.

Comment: @EyalShilony, there is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26009350/1679310 in which I created a plunker showing how to use html5. Does it help?

Comment: Unfortunately not but I solved it! I'll provide the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing ng-include with ui-view.

```
<div id="dashboard" data-ui-view data-prevent-touch-scroll></div>
```

My router looks like this.

```
export class Router {
    /* tslint:disable no-unused-variable */
    private static $inject: string[] = ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider"];
    /* tslint:enable no-unused-variable */

    constructor($state: ng.ui.IStateProvider, $urlRouter: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider, $location: ng.ILocationProvider) {
        $urlRouter.otherwise("/");

        $state.state("default", {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "/views/master.html",
            onEnter: ["$state", "$timeout", ($state: ng.ui.IStateService, $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) => {
                $timeout(() => {
                    $state.go("default.master");
                });
            }]
        });

        $state.state("default.master", {
            views: {
                "header": {
                    templateUrl: "/views/layout/header.html"
                },
                "sidebar": {
                    templateUrl: "/views/layout/side-menu.html"
                },
                "": {
                    templateUrl: "/views/workspace/index.html"
                },
                "footer": {
                },
            }
        });

        $location.html5Mode(true);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether it's a solution or a hack but it works. :)